# When I was trying to run this program in the codeblocks compiler, the strstr() function was returning 0 everytime. Why?

Tags: c, string, codeblocks, strstr

I was making a program to search a track from a list of tracks by getting an input string from user.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
                        "I left my heart in harvard med school",
                        "Newark, newark - a wonderful town",
                        "Dancing with a dork",
                        "From here to maternity",
                        "The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i, m = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
```

> the control reaches upto this line of code

```
        m = strstr(tracks[i], search_for);     
        if(m)
        {
            printf("Track%i : '%s' \n", i, tracks[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

> strstr() returns 0

```
int main()
{
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0 ;

}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905728/strstr-function

Comment: It contains a newline in the `search_for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that `fgets` includes any trailing `newline` that was part of the entry. It can be removed like this

```
search_for [ strcspn(search_for, "\r\n") ] = 0;   // remove trailing newline etc
```

otherwise you won't find a match.

Note that `fflush(stdin);` is non-standard. Note too that the `scanf` given in one of the linked answers stops at the first whitespace, unless you use certain formatting to prevent it.

Comment: This program is working now. But I would like to know why I shouldn't use `fflush(stdin)`?

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is not part of the standard C implementation, but it is defined in MSVC and perhaps other implementations. So it is not portable.

Comment: I have posted a new question. When I researched I found that using `fflush(stdin)` will help me out. Should I use it or search for an alternate solution?

Comment: Only use it if it is documented by your compiler manual and you are willing to write non-portable code.